# Defining a Keras Custom Layer that adds a random value to a flatten layer output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

How to define a Keras Custom Layer to add a random value to the output of a Flatten layer (of a CNN) of size (None, 100)?

Comment: I think u simply need https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GaussianNoise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

```py
class Noise(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mean=0, stddev=1.0, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Noise, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.mean = mean
        self.stddev = stddev

    def call(self, inputs, 
             training=False # Only add noise in training!
             ):
        if training:
            return inputs + tf.random.normal(
                inputs.shape, 
                mean=self.mean,
                stddev=self.stddev
            ) # Add random noise during training
        else:
            return inputs + tf.fill(
                inputs.shape, 
                self.mean
            ) # Add mean of random noise during inference

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,10,1)),
    Noise(stddev=.1)
])

model(input_batch,
      training=True # Defaults to False. 
                    # Noise is added only in training mode.
)
```

[Full example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x0ptgj1CkcDdlAFHJ8m25Lcg6AMW4-Qt?usp=sharing).

There is also a built-in `keras.layers.GaussianNoise` layer that does same exact thing as my `Noise` above.

Several notes to bear in mind when implementing above code:

- If you intend to use random noise as a regularizer to fight [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting), it is much, much better to use keras' built-in [image augmentation module](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).
- Avoid using non-normal distributions when dealing with CNNs. Using uniform distribution, for example, will shift mean value of a batch, negating all image normalization that CNNs so [desperately need](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/220970/295487).
- Consider using dropout if the results of flatten is fed into dense classifiers on the top. Dropout is much more efficient in what you are probably trying to do.

For any clarification, please don't hesitate to comment!
Cheers.

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I know, it's conspicuous. Question was specific about a 'custom layer'. So I refrained from just commenting that there is `keras.layers.GaussianNoise` that does same thing. If author wants a custom layer, this is one way to do it.

Comment: This will be biased during inference. If `training=True`, you should add the mean value of the noise: `inputs + tf.fill(inputs.shape, value=self.mean)`

Comment: And I believe your bullet points are out of scope for this question

Comment: @NicolasGervais I believe you meant  "if `training=False`, you should add ...", am I correct? Could you also please cite any paper or an in-depth explanation of why should I add mean value of noise during inference?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, thank you for paying attention. I meant if `training=False`. Similar to batch normalization, you need a representative value during testing. If your noise has mean M during training and mean 0 during inference, everything will be off by M. That could be addressed by having `self.mean = 0` too.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now. Dropout also uses [input scaling during inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/331010/295487) for that same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class add_random(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def call(self, input):
    return input + tf.random.uniform((1,))
```